# Error while upgrading from TYPO3 4 to TYPO3 4.5

Tags: typo3

I need to update my TYPO3 4 to 4.5.
I installed 4.5 and symlinked to the new source. The problem is that I can't get into TYPO3 4.5 install tool using localhost/typo3/install. It shows "page isn't working".
How do I get into TYPO3 4.5 install tool?

Comment: If you have less content on your page maybe you are faster with a new installation of TYPO3 8.7 LTS and copy/paste the content. Because you have to update to 4.5, then to 6.2, then to 7.6 and at least 8.7. Maybe you have to replace unsupported extensions and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Page isn't working` is a default error message when a site returns a 500 error. You'll need to check your error log to see whet the error actually is.

Also TYPO3 4.5 is old, not maintained anymore and not secure. You should not use it. Please update to at least 7.6.

Answer (score 0):

In the folder `typo3conf` are some files like:

- temp_CACHED_**ps12c3**_ext_localconf.php
- temp_CACHED_**ps12c3**_ext_tables.php

The bold part might probably different but those files you can delete and then try again.
Also make sure that you meet the requirements concerning PHP-version and MySQL-version.

The deleted files will be created new, so you aren't deleting unique information, but the new files differ a bit.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue can be the PHP version. I am running Typo3 4.5 successfully on PHP 5.3. However it will not run on higher PHP version. However, if the update is done on the same server, then PHP version issue might not be applicable.

The exact error detail will come up in the PHP error_log. Make sure that error logging is enabled in the PHP.ini setting.